# Proving an inequality involving three real numbers

Tags: inequality

For any numbers $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $\frac{3}{2} (a^2+b^2+c^2+1) \geq a(b+1) +b(c+1)+ c(a+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Left minus right can be written as
$$
\frac {a^2}{2}-ab+\frac {b^2}{2}
+\frac {b^2}{2}-bc+\frac {c^2}{2}
+\frac {c^2}{2}-ac+\frac {a^2}{2}
+\frac {a^2}{2}-a+\frac {1}{2}
+\frac {b^2}{2}-b+\frac {1}{2}
+\frac {c^2}{2}-c+\frac {1}{2},
$$
which is just
$$
\frac 12(a-b)^2+\frac 12(b-c)^2+\frac 12(c-a)^2+\frac 12(a-1)^2+\frac 12(b-1)^2+\frac 12(c-1)^2\geq 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$a^2+b^2+c^2-2a-2b-2c+3[=(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2]\geq 0.$
Also $2a^2+2b^2+2c^2- 2ab-2bc-2ca\geq 0.$ Adding the two expressions give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

By the **Cauchy-Schwarz** inequality *twice* for the right hand side:
$a(b+1)+b(c+1)+c(a+1)\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\cdot \sqrt{(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2+(a+1)^2}\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\cdot \sqrt{2(b^2+1)+2(c^2+1)+2(a^2+1)}= \sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{2x+6}, x = a^2+b^2+c^2.$.

Next we prove: $\sqrt{x(2x+6)} \le \dfrac{3(x+1)}{2}\iff 2x^2+6x \le \dfrac{9}{4}\cdot (x^2+2x+1)\iff 8x^2+24x \le 9x^2+18x+9\iff 0 \le x^2-6x+9 \iff 0 \le (x-3)^2$, which is clearly true.

Equality occurs when $a = b = c = 1$.